# How to send a format parameter to a show action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't seem to figure out how to pass a parameter to a show action without breaking the route. I am trying this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('excell.jpg'), affiliate_path(id: @affiliate.id, format: 'xls') %>
```

But I get this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"affiliates", :id=>nil, :format=>"xls"}
```

Why is the id not being passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the `id:` option, pass the entire object as the first argument to the helper:

```
affiliate_path(@affiliate, format: 'xls')
```

Comment: Oops, this works, but my original code works too. It was breaking because `@affiliate` was not a proper object (because of some other nonsense I was doing in the model). What a waste, sorry!

Comment: Should this post be deleted?